# Laravel Dynamic Route names depends on optional route param

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-10

In Laravel 10, I have routes that are structured like the following:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:edit-settings']], function () {
    $module_name = 'settings';
    $controller_name = 'SettingController';

    Route::get("$module_name/{settingModule?}", "$controller_name@index")
});
```

I have tried with

```php
Route::get("$module_name/{settingModule?}", "$controller_name@index")->name(function ($parameters) {
    $settingModule = $parameters['settingModule'] ?? 'settings';
    return $settingModule . 'index';
});
```

My requirement is to generate the route name dynamically based on the route parameter, but it throws an error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Comment: You cannot pass a closure to `->name()`, it has to be a `string`.

Comment: @Remul, I think you are right, i am unable to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: routes are save in memory during runtime, It should not be possible to pass the route paramater as part of route name because that never existed until someone makes a request to that specific route. and even if its possible, imagine someone doing a thousand, or a million request to that route with unique param each, your application will keep storing it and your poor memory will explode lol

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, you can dynamically generate route names using the `name()` method. However, you cannot directly pass a closure to the `name()` method. To achieve dynamic route names based on the route parameter, you can use the `as()` method instead.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:edit-settings']], function () {
    $module_name = 'settings';
    $controller_name = 'SettingController';

    Route::get("$module_name/{settingModule?}", "$controller_name@index")
        ->as(function ($parameters) use ($module_name) {
            $settingModule = $parameters['settingModule'] ?? 'settings';
            return $settingModule . '.' . $module_name . '.index';
        });
});
```

In this example, the `as()` method is used to dynamically generate the route name. It takes a string as an argument, so you can concatenate the route parameters and other values to form a unique name for the route. In this case, the route name will be generated as `setting.index` or `setting.someParamValue.index` depending on the `settingModule` parameter.

Note that the route name should be unique across your application to avoid conflicts.

Comment: It throws an error : Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::as does not exist.

Comment: Did ChatGPT write that answer?